# Extending class in sibling imported file not working

Tags: sass, extend, gulp-sass, node-sass

I'm trying to use Sass's `@extend` feature to cut down on duplicate code, and for some reason, it's throwing an error. Example code below.

In `_title.scss`:

```
.title { font-family: "Open Sans"; }
```

In `_user-content.scss`

```
.user-content { h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { @extend .title; } }
```

In `screen.scss`:

```
@import "_title";
@import "_user-content";
```

When running `gulp-sass`:

```
[13:15:02] gulp-notify: [Gulp] src/assets/styles/base/user-content/_user-content.scss
Error: ".user-content h1" failed to @extend ".title".
       The selector ".title" was not found.
       Use "@extend .title !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
        on line 1 of src/assets/styles/base/user-content/_user-content.scss
>> .user-content { h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { @extend .title; } }
   -----------------------------------------^
```

This seems correct to me, but it's throwing an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was just being dumb. I had forgotten that I had two SCSS files, one `screen.scss` and one `editor.scss`. The import was working just fine in `screen.scss`, but failing in `editor.scss`, because I hadn't imported the class I was trying to extend in to `editor.scss`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to import "_title" into "_user-content". I'm not sure you can access imported classes from another imported file.